# Outputcache and HttpModule

Tags: httpmodule, outputcache

I have an HTTP module that replaces relative URLs with the URL of our CDN for static content.  However, when this module is added to the web.config, it causes our Outputcache to no longer work.

I've tried messing with the order of httpModules in web.config with no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: I am using varybycustom.  And this is for webforms, btw

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you call Response.End() in your HttpModule.
Rick Strahl writes:

> ...Specifying the Response.End() code at the end of the request causes
>   UpdateRequestCache() to never fire and put the content into the cache.
>   More info there: [Don’t use Response.End() with OutputCache](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/May/21/Dont-use-ResponseEnd-with-OutputCache)